# adding predictions for logistic regression (grouped variable)

Tags: r, dplyr, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a logistic regression by grouping 
I tried all the methods , that have been listed, yet i keep getting the following error

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :    no applicable method for 'predict'
>   applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

```
 # analysis ----------------------------------------------------------------
    models<-  df %>% 
    group_by(organ) %>% 
    do(model = glm(IHC ~ Dose,
                     data = .,
                     family = binomial(logit))) %>%
    ungroup

    new<-predict(models, newdata = data.frame(dose=1:10))

    Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
      no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"


Organ_factor     organ                        Dose IHC
1             1   Diaphragm                   0.00   0
2             2   Diaphragm inflammation      0.00   0
3             3   Heart cell                  0.00   0
4             5   Heart  mixed cell           0.00   0
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Right now the problem is that all your models are in a tibble. You would need to map predict over that model column.

Comment: I can't test possible solutions without something I can copy/paste into R. Maybe edit your question just to use a built-in data set for demonstration purposes. Or maybe these questions do what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168341/make-prediction-for-each-group-differently or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924571/add-predictions-for-models-by-group (`glm` and `lm` should behave the same here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `augment()` from the broom package, combined with nest/map/unnest.

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)

models <- df %>%
  group_by(organ) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ glm(IHC ~ Dose, data = ., family = binomial(logit)),
         augmented = map2(model, data, augment))

models %>%
  unnest(augmented)
```

The predicted values will be in the column `.fitted`.

Note that they'll be on a logit scale: you may want to add `type.predict = "response"` as an argument to the augment function if you want them to be probabilities.

Comment: I suspect there are values of `organ` for which there are no non-NA values of `IHC`, `Dose`, or both. Try putting `filter(!is.na(IHC), !is.na(Dose))` before the `group_by()`.

Comment: you were correct there were NAs, now i have the model run, however i am still unable to use augment , in the way the documentation shows. the error i get is : models %>%
  unnest(augmented)                                                                                               Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The column `augmented` doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you include the line `augmented = map2(model, data, augment)` as shown above?

Comment: hey @david - yeap i did